# Jquery table Sorter , sorting is working only one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

When the labels are clicked, i am showing dynamic data and this is working fine with table sorter. Clicking on the table headers is sorting the table rows.

The issue i am facing is, after clicking the label "One" and *then* clicking on label "Two", and trying to sort data from the second response, it stops working from here onwards.

This is my code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".candlespattern", function() {

    var clicked = $(this).attr("id");
    var datatoselect = '';

    if (clicked === 'one') {
        datatoselect = myjsonresponse1;
    } else if (clicked === 'two') {
        datatoselect = myjsonresponse2;
    }

    var html = "";
    html += '<thead><th class="thheaders">Symbol</th><th class="thheaders">Date</th></thead><tbody>';
    for (var e = 0; e < datatoselect.length; e++) {
        html += "<tr><td>" + datatoselect[e].name + "</td><td>" + datatoselect[e].date_time + "</td></tr>"
    }

    $("#candletable").html(html);

    $('#candletable').tablesorter({}).tablesorterPager({
        container: $(".pager"),
        size: 20
    });
    $("#candletable").trigger("update");

    $("#pager").show();
});
```

[Here is JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eY8uH/1491/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so after researching this particular plugin, I came across a [useful example](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-empty-table.html#).
First of all, your problem is most likely that you are overwriting the `thead` of the table **each** time the item is clicked leading to the plugin to lose some references. Here's how I suggest you do it:

Since the `thead` is the same for both responses, there's no need to add it dynamically each time and we can just put it in the HTML:

```
<table id="candletable" class="table table-striped tablesorter">
    <!-- add the table head and an empty tbody -->
    <thead>
        <th class="thheaders">Symbol</th>
        <th class="thheaders">Date</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Next thing is that we should initialize the `tablesorter` only once, and then just update the data:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    // initialize the table sorter on document.ready
    $('#candletable').tablesorter({}).tablesorterPager({
        container: $(".pager"),
        size: 20
    });

    $("#pager").hide();
});
```

Finally, we remove the `thead` data and the initialization from the click handler and add the created table rows to `tbody`:

```
$(document).on("click", ".candlespattern", function() {

    var clicked = $(this).attr("id");
    var datatoselect = '';

    if (clicked === 'one') {
        datatoselect = myjsonresponse1;
    } else if (clicked === 'two') {
        datatoselect = myjsonresponse2;
    }

    // create the table rows from the response
    var html = ""; 
    for (var e = 0; e < datatoselect.length; e++) {
        html += "<tr><td>" + datatoselect[e].name + "</td><td>" + datatoselect[e].date_time + "</td></tr>"
    }

    // add the rows to table body
    $("#candletable tbody").html(html);

    // update the table
    $("#candletable").trigger("update");

    // show it
    $("#pager").show();
});
```

### Here's a working FIDDLE

Comment: Thanks  a lot  working great, Could you please tell me how to show Sorting Icons in table Header

Comment: If you change the class names on the headers, then you'll need to modify the css. *Please note* that the demo is using tablesorter from my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) while this answer is referencing the original plugin - there are slight differences, like the [`theme` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#theme).